# How to access NSString constants (keys) in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsstring, constants

in Objective-C we all used to create NSString constants to store and access information in NSDictionaries, or for unique names of NSNotifications.

```objc
// in MYClass.h
FOUNDATION_EXTERN NSString * const kMYNotificationName;

// in MYClass.m
NSString * const kMYNotificationName = @"my.app.notification";

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kMYNotificationName object:self userInfo:nil];
```

Now, using Xcode 6's [Mix and Match](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) I want to register for this particular NSNotification in a Swift class:

```swift
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
                    .addObserver(self, 
                                 selector:"notificationReceived:", 
                                 name:kMYNotificationName, 
                                 object:nil)
```

The compile error is "Use of unresolved identifier 'kMYNotificationName'", and there's nothing I can do about it.

Low-hanging fruits I've already checked are:

- The Objective-C header file is included in the Bridging-Header
- The Bridging-Header is included before the swift Header is loaded (constants are not types but who knows)

Is there anything you can point me at? Any workarounds except from "use the string directly"?

Thank you very much in advance,
Flo

Comment: sorry, I fixed the example. Those are not the keys that I am using, I cleaned those for confidentiality reasons. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: No problem, just tried this out in an app and seems to work for me.

Comment: Your example works for me. Are you running Xcode6-Beta7? Did you try deleting your build and DerivedData folder and rebuilding your project?

Comment: Has anyone sorted out how to do this? Someone must have, right?

Comment: Just built a new project, and it worked. In the Project's Build Settings, is the `Objective-C Bridging Header` pointing to the right file, and the build target is using `$(inherited)`?

Also, is the Objective-C a framework, or included in the code?

Comment: I have the same problem and it the Swift implementation file does not see my constant :-( Where should I use the '$(inherited)' flag @Can